# Delete parent field from formBuilder angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to delete a parent field from my form

This is my example:

```
  initForm() {
    return this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [this.data.startDate?this.data.startDate:new Date().toISOString(),Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      dateDeposit: [this.data.dateDeposit?this.data.dateDeposit:new Date().toISOString(),Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  comment: [this.data.comment?this.data.comment:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
firstName: [this.data.firstName?this.data.comment:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
lastName: [this.data.lastName?this.data.comment:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
adress: [this.data.adress?this.data.comment:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],

remarks: [this.data.remarks?this.data.remarks:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],

otherRemarks: [this.data.otherRemarks?this.data.otherRemarks:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
contactClient: [this.data.contactClient?this.data.contactClient:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
clientNumber: [this.data.clientNumber?this.data.clientNumber:"",Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
  }
```

Then I send the this.myForm.value as an object on my HTTP request.

```
   this.myService.putForm(this.myForm.value).subscribe();
```

The problem is that I do not want to send dateDeposit.
How can I delete DateDeposit from myForm when I send the myForm.value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send just the `startDate`. Try:

```
this.myService.putForm(this.myForm.get('startDate').value).subscribe();
```

or

```
this.myService.putForm(this.myForm.controls['startDate'].value).subscribe();
```

If you mean to use all other values, but `dateDeposit`, you can:

```
// get form value without dateDeposit
let formValue = Object.assign({}, this.myForm.value);
delete formValue.dateDeposit;
// submit form value without dateDeposit
this.myService.putForm(formValue).subscribe();
```

Comment: Hm, what do you mean by "multiple parent field"? What parent?

Comment: I will give you an example; If I have dateDeposit, startDate, firstName, lastName and 30 ohters parent filed and I want only delete dateDeposit. What can I do ?

Comment: You can clone the form value and delete the `dateDeposit`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use

```
this.myService.putForm(this.myForm.value.startDate).subscribe();
```

Comment: multiple parent means ? can you update your question

Answer (score 0):

```
this.myForm.removeControl('depositDate')
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removeControl

you can simply remove the control from the form itself, but be aware it might create issues in the template since there is an input tag bound to this formControl